# Wordpress : Post Content Need in the bootstrap modals without repeating the model in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show content in the popup on the click of the content title text.  Somehow i have achieve this thing but, i have put that popup in the `while loop`. So, popup will be created as much post are there. Is there a way to create a single popup outside the loop  and display the content whatever title has been clicked. I have try and search using jquery but did not get any success.

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while( $slides->have_posts() ) : $slides->the_post(); 
$i++;
?>
<div class="vc_span2 wpb_column column_container col no-extra-padding">
  <div> <a class="call_model" rel="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal<? echo $i ?>" style="display: inline; opacity: 0;">
    <?php the_title();  ?>
    </a> </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<? echo $i ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
        <?php   echo $post->post_content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Try loading the contents of modal (modal-body) using Ajax before poping-up the modal.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on 2 methods

1) Jason / Ajax

create a php file that capable to call the post contend depends on the post id. Create a jason call on the click of the title, pass the currently clicked link id through the json call and rerun the content from the newly created php file. Through the json response method catch the content aand append to the model area and load the model.

2) Normal method.

add new data attribute in the a href tag and add common class too

```
<a **data-ref="<?=echo$i;?>"** class="mod call_model" rel="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal<? echo $i ?>" style="display: inline; opacity: 0;">
<?php the_title();  ?>
```

create new div with hidden mode like

```
<div class="text<?=echo $i?>" style="display:none"></div>
```

suppose $i is 1 the data-ref=1 and the text class is text1

then i create a query for click on a.

> `$('body').on('click', '.mod', function()
>       {
>          var id = $(this).data('ref'); //here i got the id of the clicked link
>          var textbox = '.text'+id;
>          var text    = $(textbox).html();//here i got the content from the content div.
>          $('#myModal').modal('show'); // here manually load the model
>          $('.modal-body').html(text);// here manually inject the text taken from the hidden field to the modal text area.
>   });`

Then you can define your modal html anywhere out side the loop. On clicking on the link that will populated with the text from your hidden div.

These are just a concept you need to work on the codes depends on your site.